# Hudson Central Authentication Service

Tags: java, cas, hudson-plugins

I'm working for a client. This client uses Hudson for Continuous Integration and wants to authenticate users through the standard Central Authentication Service (CAS). So I tried to develop a plugin to add to Hudson in order to set up CAS.
I began to develop a plugin from the existing plugin "cas1". It's the first time I developed a plugin for Hudson.  And I created a java class extending `SecurityRealm`. When I launch Hudson and go to the Hudson management -> Manage Security, I choose the CAS security (my new plugin) and enter the CAS URL, the Hudson HostName URL and save it. The sign-up link appears at the top right of the page.

I want to redirect the page to the CAS authentication page when the user clicks on the sign-up link.

How can I do that?

I tried to modify the following HTML code in order to avoid the display of the basic authentication dialog box of Hudson.

```
<a onclick="showLoginDialog(); return false;" href="/login?from=%2F">
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to redirect Hudson authentication to the CAS authentication page, overriding the method "getLoginUrl()":

```
@Override
public String getLoginUrl() {
    return casServerUrl;
}
```

and adding my own "loginLink.jelly" file in the package "resources/myCasSecurityRealm". And in this file, I replaced the link:

```
<a style="color:inherit" href="${rootURL}/${app.securityRealm.loginUrl}?from=${from}"><b>${%login}</b></a>
```

by

```
<a style="color:inherit" href="${app.securityRealm.loginUrl}"><b>${%login}</b></a>
```

Now, when I click on the sign-up link, my CAS authentication page is displayed.